# how to get the DDL of a table with different schema

Tags: oracle

I have few databases and all the databases have the same tables (i.e. table names). Now i want to get the DDL of the table with different schema.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `dbms_metadata` package to get the DDL of any object of the DB.

```
SELECT
    DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('<Object type>', '<Object name>', '<object schema>')
FROM
    DUAL; -- How to

SELECT
    DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE', 'MY_TABLE', 'MY_SCHEMA')
FROM
    DUAL; -- In your case use something like this
```

Also, You can format the output using `dbms_metadata.set_transform_param`.

See [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_metada.htm#i1019125) for more information on it.

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you very much Tejash for all your efforts.

Comment: Sir , can you please explain how it can be done with cx_Oracle and python3 @ Tejash

Comment: I think I will not be able to answer the question that you have asked in the comment as I am an expert of only Oracle DB